# Permanently Downcast c++ Pointer

Tags: c++

So this is probably a weird question, but I have a reasonably good reason for asking.

The gist of my question is, given an example with two levels of derivation on a class hierarchy:

Main Base Class:

```
class Animal
{
  virtual void Draw() = 0;
};
```

Derived Class:

```
class Dog : public Animal
{
  virtual void Draw()
  {
    // draw a generic dog icon or something...
  }
};
```

Further Derivation:

```
class Corgi : public Dog
{
  virtual void Draw()
  {
    // draw a corgi icon...
  }
};
```

Now, I'd love to be able to, from within the `Corgi` class, permanently downcast the 'this' pointer to a `Dog` pointer and then pass it off somewhere else as an Animal. This other place will then be able to call the `Draw` function and get the `Dog` method, not the virtual `Corgi` method. I know this is strange, but again, I have a vaguely legitimate reason for wanting to do it.

I've tried all the different casting operators and haven't had any luck, but maybe there is a consistent way of pulling this off? In the past I've caused myself trouble by not properly using `dynamic_cast` which resulted in a similar state for a pointer. Perhaps this time I can use that to my advantage?

**Edit:**
Perhaps the above example doesn't illustrate clearly the what I'm trying to achieve, so I'll elaborate with my real goal.

I'm trying to achieve a shorthand for registering base class implementations that link into a scripting system I've been using for a while. The scripting system relies on a base class `IScriptContext` to facilitate access to real-code functions and member variable access. Internally base classes register their member function addresses and member variable addresses which are later dispatched/accessed through lookup tables. I'm in the process of adding proper support for class derivation hierarchies to the scripting system, and I figured being able to isolate the base class versions of these interfaces would help save time and make the whole process cleaner for me when it comes time to register available base classes with the script interpreter. There are other ways to achieve this, such as registering class specific function pointers for each required method for each available base class (e.g. `this->Dog::CallFunction`, `this->Dog::SetMember`, `this->Dog::GetMember`.) However, I figured using an interface would allow me to modify things a bit easier down the road if I ever needed to.

I hope all of that makes some kind of sense.

Thanks!

Comment: `I know this is strange, but again, I have a vaguely legitimate reason for wanting to do it.` This sentence contains a contradiction. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I think you meant `upcasting`, not `downcasting`.

Comment: If your `Corgi` objects need to behave like `Dog`s, then they should contain code to cause them to behave that way. Perhaps an `isDog` flag along with a test in `Draw`, like `if (isDog) { Dog::Draw(); return; }`.

Comment: @David: All `Corgi`s are already `Dog`s, and should probably already be invoking `Dog::Draw()`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That was a poor choice of names on my part. Obviously, they must be or `Dog::Draw()` wouldn't even work. Perhaps `isJustDog` or `actLikeDog` would be a better name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `Corgi` object. You can:

1. Treat it as a `Dog` object everywhere by using the `Dog::` qualifier to all calls (e.g. `ptr->Dog::draw();`). This loses you virtual dispatch, and is almost certainly not what you want from how your question reads.
2. Actually construct a new `Dog` object from your `Corgi`. Just do this with a normal `static_cast` as you'd convert any other type or let implicit conversion take over (e.g. `Corgi c; Dog d(c);`).

These are the options available to you. To want to retain a `Corgi` but automatically pretend everywhere that it's a `Dog` is neither reasonable nor legitimate, so the language does not provide for it.

Comment: I suppose I'll have to go down this road. It'll be less flexible down the road, but it looks like my only option. Thanks!

Comment: @worstoo: I realise that you've already thrown away this option as being _too popular_ for whatever reason (NIH?) but I would like to re-iterate the suggestion that you take a step back and think about what it is that you are trying to accomplish. Hopefully this will result in a reconsideration about your design.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start off by saying your design looks faulty.

You can however explicitly say which function in a hierarchy you want to call:

```
Corgi* corgi = new Corgi;
corgi->Dog::draw();
```

This will call the `draw` method from `Dog`, not from `Corgi`. (I hope I understood correctly what you're asking).

Answer (score 2):

Tomalak has [already outlined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14076349/464581) two of the main choices available to you:

- use qualified calls, or
- construct a `Dog` as a `Dog` copy of your `Corgi`.

In addition to these, you can

- use a simple *wrapper*

e.g.

```
class LooksLikeDog
    : public Dog
{
private:
    Dog*  realObject_;

    LooksLikeDog( LooksLikeDog const& );                    // No such.
    LooksLikeDog& operator=( LooksLikeDog const& );         // No such.

public:
    LooksLikeDog( Dog& other )
        : realObject_( &other )
    {}

    // Just for exposition: not implementing this does the same.
    virtual void draw() override { Dog::draw(); }

    // Example of other method that may need to be implemented:
    virtual void bark() override { realObject_->bark(); }
};
```

But the best solution is most probably to **fix your design**. ;-)

Comment: Who is this mystical, marvellous "Tomalak" character of whom you speak, Cheers and hth. - Alf?

Answer (score 0):

Implement Corgi draw function and call your parent's implementation:

```
virtual void Corgi::Draw() 
{ 
    Dog::draw(); 
}
```